# Error 255 samba share simple file share Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: samba

I have been using simple file share on Ubuntu 12.04 for several years not a problem now I have up graded to 14.04 all the problems error 255, tried all sights to fix the problem nothing works even went back to 12.04 still the same problem`error 255`

'net usershare' returned `error 255: net usershare add: cannot convert name "Everyone" to a SID. The connection was refused.` Maybe smbd is not running.

There appears to be a bug with the new upgrade or has there been a new upgrade.